# Trying to replace a list of strings with another list of strings in a bigger string?

Tags: python

I'm starting to tunnel on this code and would like someone's guidance. Basically, I want to replace my `blank_space` in my string `driver_knowldege_test` with the list `answer_1`. I would like it to go in order too (which is why I'm using the index), but this is where I also found myself stuck. I'm not even sure if the words are replacing each other properly either.

```
driver_knowledge_test = "When you're going to drive it is important to 
always put on your ___1___, including your passengers. \nIf there are no 
lanes marked on the road, you should drive in the ___2___ side of the road.             
\nIt's getting dark and the sun is fading, you should turn on the ___3___. 
\nBefore driving on a freeway, you should make sure you have enough ___4___, 
oil, water and the correct tyre pressure."
answer_1 = ['seatbelts', 'left', 'light', 'fuel']

blank_space = ["___1___", "___2___", "___3___", "___4___"]

def replace_blank_space(blank, sentence, answer):
replaced = []
sentence = sentence.split()
answer = 0
blank_space = 0
for word in sentence:
    replacements = finding_blank(word, list_of_blank)
    if word_to_be_replaced != None:
        word = word.replace(replacements, answer)
        replaced.append(word)
        answer += 1
        blank_space += 1
    else:
        replaced.append(word)
replaced = " ".join(replaced)
return replaced

def finding_blank(word, list_of_blank):
for ea_blank in blank_space:
    if ea_blank in blank_space: #This equals to teh whole list.
        return ea_blank
return None




print replace_blank_space(blank_space, driver_knowledge_test, answer_1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's necessary to `split` the paragraph or search for blanks or anything here. Just call `replace` like normal.

```
driver_knowledge_test = "When you're going to drive it is important to \
always put on your ___1___, including your passengers. \nIf there are no \
lanes marked on the road, you should drive in the ___2___ side of the road. \
\nIt's getting dark and the sun is fading, you should turn on the ___3___. \
\nBefore driving on a freeway, you should make sure you have enough ___4___, \
oil, water and the correct tyre pressure."

answer_1 = ['seatbelts', 'left', 'light', 'fuel']
blank_space = ["___1___", "___2___", "___3___", "___4___"]

for space, answer in zip(blank_space, answer_1):
    driver_knowledge_test = driver_knowledge_test.replace(space, answer)

print(driver_knowledge_test)
```

Result:

```
When you're going to drive it is important to always put on your seatbelts, including your passengers.
If there are no lanes marked on the road, you should drive in the left side of the road.
It's getting dark and the sun is fading, you should turn on the light.
Before driving on a freeway, you should make sure you have enough fuel, oil, water and the correct tyre pressure.
```

Comment: Very elegant solution using replace!

Comment: How would you go about it when you want to put a 'raw_input' function, where if the user guesses ccorrectly you go on to fill the next blank space?

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Kevin's answer, except demonstrating solution using split:

```
import string
answer_1 = ['seatbelts', 'left', 'light', 'fuel']

blank_space = ["___1___", "___2___", "___3___", "___4___"]

answer = {blank_space[i]:answer_1[i] for i in range(len(answer_1))}

driver_knowledge_test = "When you're going to drive it is important to 
always put on your ___1___, including your passengers. \nIf there are no lanes marked on the road, you should drive in the ___2___ side of the road.\nIt's getting dark and the sun is fading, you should turn on the ___3___. \nBefore driving on a freeway, you should make sure you have enough ___4___, oil, water and the correct tyre pressure."

new_answer = driver_knowledge_test.split()

final_answer = [i.strip(i[len(i)-1]) if i[len(i)-1] in string.punctuation else i for i in new_answer]

print ' '.join([answer[i] if i in answer.keys() else i for i in final_answer])
```

Output:

```
When you're going to drive it is important to always put on your seatbelts including your passengers If there are no lanes marked on the road you should drive in the 2 side of the road It's getting dark and the sun is fading you should turn on the light Before driving on a freeway you should make sure you have enough fuel oil water and the correct tyre pressure
```